# Binding not working for some UI-Elements

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm creating a UI that gets it's values from a DataModel outside.

One value is called `speed` and should be visible as Text and on a speedometer which I created earlier.

The text works fine:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Speed, Converter={StaticResource converterValueSpeedNumber}}"/>
```

But the speedo doesnt:

```
<View:RoundMeter MeterValue="{Binding Speed, Converter={StaticResource converterValueSpeedRoundMeter}}"/>
```

Even using no converter at all or the same converter doesn't change a thing.

Another UI element has the same issue: text working, round instrument doesn't. But when I bind these values to a Slider they work all simultaniously.

Any ideas what might cause such a problem?

**Edit:**
In my MainWindow.xaml I call the RoundMeter with the MeterValue like shown above.
Inside of this UserControl I call a different Element:

```
<view:CircularProgressBar Percentage="{Binding Path=MeterValue, FallbackValue=0.0}"/>
```

And this is not called.
Other parameters are passed as numbers from the MainWindow and passed to this CircularProgressBar as Binding Path=ParameterName. This works. But the main value is bound in the MainWindow AND in the UserControl. That causes the problem.

I could call the Parent's value from the UserControl but I need different Converters for different RoundMeters that's why I did it this way. Should I rethink my programm's design or is it still possible to pass it like this?

Comment: Maybe the RoundMeter object has the DataContext setted via code?

Comment: Test setting values to the speedo explicitly, maybe RoundMeter just doesn't work as planned.

Comment: Yess O-o
Thank you, Riccardo. In the UserControl it says: `this.DataContext = this;` How do I bind to this then?

// I tried setting the values explicitelly and it worked. Guess the mystery was the DataContext :O

Comment: Ok, a bit different quesition in the `Edit:` above.